# Filtering another stream based on item in current stream using rxpy

Tags: python, rx-py

I want to find a match in another stream and combine it with current item.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers_in_char = ["2", "1", "3", "5", "4"]

textnumbers_in_stream = rx.defer(rx.from_iterable(numbers_in_char))


def exists_in_words(number, words):
    return words.pipe(
        op.filter(lambda w: int(w) == number),
        op.map(lambda w: (number, w))
    )


rx \
    .from_iterable(numbers) \
    .pipe(op.map(lambda number: exists_in_words(number, textnumbers_in_stream))) \
    .subscribe(lambda row: print(row))
```

I expect to have these printed:

```
(1,"1")
(2,"2")
(3,"3")
...
```

But I have:

```
None
None
None
...
```

Someone can give me an idea what i have done wrong?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement here:

```
def exists_in_words(number, words):
    return words.pipe(
        op.filter(lambda w: int(w) == number),
        op.map(lambda w: (number, w))
    )
```

If you change this to print the tuple:

```
rx.from_iterable(numbers) \
    .pipe(op.map(lambda number: exists_in_words(number, textnumbers_in_stream))) \
    .subscribe(lambda row: print(row[0], row[1]))
```

The output is:

```
<rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df898> <rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1dfba8>
<rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1dfba8> <rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df198>
<rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df198> <rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df240>
<rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df240> <rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df898>
<rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1df898> <rx.core.observable.observable.Observable object at 0x7f559b1dfba8>
```

To solve that string representation take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061208/how-can-i-extract-values-from-an-rx-observable) .

Comment: I add ```on_next```, ```on_error``` and ```on_completed``` to print an item in stream. But still it prints a tuple of number and Observable object. It seems ```exists_in_word(number, words)``` return a tuple of number and Observable not a tuple of number and number.

Answer (score 1):

```
from rx import operators as op
import rx


def exists_in_words(number, words):
    return words.pipe(
        op.filter(lambda w: int(w) == number),
        op.map(lambda w: (number, w))
    )


def my_on_next(item):
    print(f"####### {item}", flush=True)


def my_on_error(throwable):
    print(throwable)


def my_on_completed():
    print('Done')


numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers_in_char = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

text_as_numbers_in_stream = rx.from_iterable(numbers_in_char)


def print_tuple(x):
    print(f"{x[0]}:{x[1]}", flush=True)
    return x


rx \
    .from_iterable(numbers) \
    .pipe(op.flat_map(lambda number: exists_in_words(number, text_as_numbers_in_stream))) \
    .subscribe(lambda x: my_on_next(x), my_on_error, my_on_completed)
```

I find it..
I change `defer` to `.from_iterable()` for the second stream..

I filter an item from *first stream* based on *second stream* in by simply reverse the process :

```
def exists_in_words(number, words):
    return words.pipe(
        op.filter(lambda w: int(w) == number),
        op.map(lambda w: (number, w))
    )
```

later `flatMap()` filter result which is an Observable. I do it by feeling, done it many times in java reactor. Basically to remove its encloser (Observer object) and get its content...

and tadaaaaaa.. it works.

```
####### (1, '1')
####### (2, '2')
####### (3, '3')
####### (4, '4')
####### (5, '5')
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two observable element wise, you can use the [zip](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_operators.html?highlight=zip#rx.operators.zip) operator:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers_in_char = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]


d = rx.from_iterable(numbers).pipe(
    ops.zip(rx.from_iterable(numbers_in_char)),
).subscribe(lambda row: print(row))
```

This returns the expected result:

```
(1, '1')
(2, '2')
(3, '3')
(4, '4')
(5, '5')
```

Note that the current release of RxPY (3.2) has a [bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/issues/578) that prevents this example to work. You can test this with 3.1.1, or hopefully with the upcoming release.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but it didn't answer my original question.. zip combines 2 streams first element from one stream with first element another stream. My question is __to find or filter from a value in one stream (ie:1) if exists in another stream (in this case "1")__.

Comment: ok, from your original example I thought it was an element-wise combination. Your solution is the way to go: You have to iterate on "numbers_in_char" for each item in "numbers".